# Calendar made with tkinter

Tags: python, beginner, datetime, tkinter

I made a calendar that displays text documents according to month. Thankfully it works, although I could really use some help how to make it more better looking and efficient. I'm new to programming but I have horrible organization skills, and can't really understand the concept of classes, and `__init__`.

```
from Tkinter import *

months = [
    "January", "Febuary", "March", "April", "May",
    "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December" 
]

January = [
        27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 
        24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
        31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
]

Febuary = [
        31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
        14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
        28, 29, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
]

March = [
    28, 29, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
    27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
]

April = [
    27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
]   

May = [
    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
    15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,
    22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,
    29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4
]

June = [
    29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4,
    5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
    12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
    19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
    26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
]

July = [
    26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2,
    3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
    10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23,
    24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
    31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
]

August = [
    31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
    7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
    14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,
    28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
]

September = [
    28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1,
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
]

October = [
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 1,
    2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8,
    9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,
    16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
    23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
    30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
]

November = [
    30, 31, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
    13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26,
    27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3, 
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
]

December = [
    27, 28, 29, 30, 1, 2, 3,
    4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,
    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
    18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
]

ht = 2
bg1 = "blue"
fg1 = "white"
current_year = "2016"

def replace(month, operation): # "+" or "-"
    if operation == "+":
        if months.index(month) == 11:
            return months[0]
        else:   
            return months[months.index(month)+1]
    elif operation == "-":
        return months[months.index(month)-1]

def replace_back(event):        
    l1.configure(text=replace(l1["text"], "-"))

    if l1["text"] == "Febuary":
        change_month(Febuary)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "March":
        change_month(March)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "April":
        change_month(April)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "May":
        change_month(May)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "June":
        change_month(June)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "July":
        change_month(July)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "August":
        change_month(August)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "September":
        change_month(September)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "October":
        change_month(October)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "November":
        change_month(November)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "December":
        change_month(December)
        load()
    else:
        change_month(January)
        load()

def replace_back2():        
    l1.configure(text=replace(l1["text"], "-"))

    if l1["text"] == "Febuary":
        change_month(Febuary)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "March":
        change_month(March)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "April":
        change_month(April)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "May":
        change_month(May)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "June":
        change_month(June)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "July":
        change_month(July)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "August":
        change_month(August)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "September":
        change_month(September)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "October":
        change_month(October)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "November":
        change_month(November)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "December":
        change_month(December)
        load()
    else:
        change_month(January)
        load()

def replace_forward(event):
    l1.configure(text=replace(l1["text"], "+"))

    if l1["text"] == "Febuary":
        change_month(Febuary)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "March":
        change_month(March)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "April":
        change_month(April)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "May":
        change_month(May)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "June":
        change_month(June)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "July":
        change_month(July)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "August":
        change_month(August)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "September":
        change_month(September)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "October":
        change_month(October)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "November":
        change_month(November)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "December":
        change_month(December)
        load()
    else:
        change_month(January)
        load()

def replace_forward2():
    l1.configure(text=replace(l1["text"], "+"))

    if l1["text"] == "Febuary":
        change_month(Febuary)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "March":
        change_month(March)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "April":
        change_month(April)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "May":
        change_month(May)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "June":
        change_month(June)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "July":
        change_month(July)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "August":
        change_month(August)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "September":
        change_month(September)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "October":
        change_month(October)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "November":
        change_month(November)
        load()
    elif l1["text"] == "December":
        change_month(December)
        load()
    else:
        change_month(January)
        load()

def edit():
    text1.configure(state="normal")
    vb2.configure(state="normal")
    vb3.configure(state="normal")
    root.after(2000, normalize)

def normalize():
    vb2.configure(state="disabled")
    vb3.configure(state="disabled")

def save():
    s = open("Months 2016/"+l1["text"]+".txt", "w")
    text = text1.get(1.0, END)
    try:
        s.write(text.rstrip())
        s.write("\n")
    finally:
        s.close()

def load():
    text1.configure(state="normal")
    l2.configure(text=l1["text"]+" 2016")
    text = open("Months 2016/"+l1["text"]+".txt").read()
    text1.delete(1.0, END)
    text1.insert(END, text)
    text1.mark_set(INSERT, 1.0)
    text1.configure(state="disabled")

root = Tk()

root.geometry("650x400")
root.focus_set()

top1_frame = Frame(root)
top1_frame.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

bottom1_frame = Frame(root)
bottom1_frame.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

left_frame = Frame(top1_frame)
left_frame.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)

right_frame = Frame(top1_frame)
right_frame.pack(side=LEFT, expan=1, fill=BOTH)

Button(bottom1_frame, text="Testing...").pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

l2 = Label(right_frame, text="January 2016")
l2.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
text1 = Text(right_frame, height=15, width=30)
text1.pack(expand=1, fill=Y)

bottom1_frame2 = Frame(right_frame)
bottom1_frame2.pack(side=BOTTOM, expand=1, fill=BOTH)

vb1 = Button(bottom1_frame2, text="Edit", command=lambda: edit())
vb2 = Button(bottom1_frame2, text="Save", state="disabled", command=lambda: save())
vb3 = Button(bottom1_frame2, text="Cancel", state="disabled", command=lambda: load())

vb1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
vb2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
vb3.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)

jan = Frame(left_frame)
jan.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
frame_days = Frame(left_frame)
frame_days.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

root.bind("<Left>", replace_back)
root.bind("<Right>", replace_forward)

b1 = Button(jan, text="<", command=replace_back2)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)
l1 = Label(jan, text="January", font="Courier 24", bg="blue", fg="white")
l1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
b2 = Button(jan, text=">", command=replace_forward2)
b2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)

load()

Label(frame_days, text="Sunday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
Label(frame_days, text="Monday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
Label(frame_days, text="Tuesday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
Label(frame_days, text="Wednesday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
Label(frame_days, text="Thursday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
Label(frame_days, text="Friday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
Label(frame_days, text="Saturday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)

frame_wk1 = Frame(left_frame)
frame_wk2 = Frame(left_frame)
frame_wk3 = Frame(left_frame)
frame_wk4 = Frame(left_frame)
frame_wk5 = Frame(left_frame)
frame_wk6 = Frame(left_frame)

frame_wk1.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
frame_wk2.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
frame_wk3.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
frame_wk4.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
frame_wk5.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
frame_wk6.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

b1 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[0], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b2 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[1], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b3 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[2], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b4 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[3], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b5 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[4], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b6 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[5], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[5])+"\n-\n"))
b7 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[6], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[6])+"\n-\n"))

b8 = Button(frame_wk2, text=January[7], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[7])+"\n-\n"))
b9 = Button(frame_wk2, text=January[8], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[8])+"\n-\n"))
b10 = Button(frame_wk2, text=January[9], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[9])+"\n-\n"))
b11 = Button(frame_wk2, text=January[10], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[10])+"\n-\n"))
b12 = Button(frame_wk2, text=January[11], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[11])+"\n-\n"))
b13 = Button(frame_wk2, text=January[12], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[12])+"\n-\n"))
b14 = Button(frame_wk2, text=January[13], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[13])+"\n-\n"))

b15 = Button(frame_wk3, text=January[14], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[14])+"\n-\n"))
b16 = Button(frame_wk3, text=January[15], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[15])+"\n-\n"))
b17 = Button(frame_wk3, text=January[16], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[16])+"\n-\n"))
b18 = Button(frame_wk3, text=January[17], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[17])+"\n-\n"))
b19 = Button(frame_wk3, text=January[18], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[18])+"\n-\n"))
b20 = Button(frame_wk3, text=January[19], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[19])+"\n-\n"))
b21 = Button(frame_wk3, text=January[20], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[20])+"\n-\n"))

b22 = Button(frame_wk4, text=January[21], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[21])+"\n-\n"))
b23 = Button(frame_wk4, text=January[22], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[22])+"\n-\n"))
b24 = Button(frame_wk4, text=January[23], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[23])+"\n-\n"))
b25 = Button(frame_wk4, text=January[24], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[24])+"\n-\n"))
b26 = Button(frame_wk4, text=January[25], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[25])+"\n-\n"))
b27 = Button(frame_wk4, text=January[26], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[26])+"\n-\n"))
b28 = Button(frame_wk4, text=January[27], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[27])+"\n-\n"))

b29 = Button(frame_wk5, text=January[28], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[28])+"\n-\n"))
b30 = Button(frame_wk5, text=January[29], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[29])+"\n-\n"))
b31 = Button(frame_wk5, text=January[30], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[30])+"\n-\n"))
b32 = Button(frame_wk5, text=January[31], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[31])+"\n-\n"))
b33 = Button(frame_wk5, text=January[32], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[32])+"\n-\n"))
b34 = Button(frame_wk5, text=January[33], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[33])+"\n-\n"))
b35 = Button(frame_wk5, text=January[34], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[34])+"\n-\n"))

b36 = Button(frame_wk6, text=January[35], height=ht, width=5, bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(January[35])+"\n-\n"))
b37 = Button(frame_wk6, text=January[36], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b38 = Button(frame_wk6, text=January[37], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b39 = Button(frame_wk6, text=January[38], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b40 = Button(frame_wk6, text=January[39], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b41 = Button(frame_wk6, text=January[40], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")
b42 = Button(frame_wk6, text=January[41], height=ht, width=5, state="disabled")

b1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)
b2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b3.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b4.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b5.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b6.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b7.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b8.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b9.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b10.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b11.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b12.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b13.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b14.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b15.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b16.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b17.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b18.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b19.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b20.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b21.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b22.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b23.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b24.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b25.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b26.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b27.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b28.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b29.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b30.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b31.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b32.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b33.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b34.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b35.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b36.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b37.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b38.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b39.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b40.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b41.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH) 
b42.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)

def upper_check(button, new_months):
    if int(new_months) < 20:
        button.configure(bg=bg1, fg=fg1, state="normal", command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months)+"\n-\n"))
    elif int(new_months) > 20:
        button.configure(bg="white", fg="black", state="disabled")

def lower_check(button, new_months):
    if int(new_months) > 20:
        button.configure(bg=bg1, fg=fg1, state="normal", command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months)+"\n-\n"))
    elif int(new_months) < 20:
        button.configure(bg="white", fg="black", state="disabled")

def change_month(new_months):
    month = str(new_months)

    b1.configure(text=new_months[0])
    upper_check(b1, new_months[0])
    b2.configure(text=new_months[1])
    upper_check(b2, new_months[1])
    b3.configure(text=new_months[2])
    upper_check(b3, new_months[2])
    b4.configure(text=new_months[3])
    upper_check(b4, new_months[3])
    b5.configure(text=new_months[4])
    upper_check(b5, new_months[4])
    b6.configure(text=new_months[5])
    upper_check(b6, new_months[5])
    b7.configure(text=new_months[6])
    upper_check(b7, new_months[6])

    b8.configure(text=new_months[7], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[7])+"\n-\n"))
    b9.configure(text=new_months[8], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[8])+"\n-\n"))
    b10.configure(text=new_months[9], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[9])+"\n-\n"))
    b11.configure(text=new_months[10], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[10])+"\n-\n"))
    b12.configure(text=new_months[11], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[11])+"\n-\n"))
    b13.configure(text=new_months[12], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[12])+"\n-\n"))
    b14.configure(text=new_months[13], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[13])+"\n-\n"))

    b15.configure(text=new_months[14], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[14])+"\n-\n"))
    b16.configure(text=new_months[15], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[15])+"\n-\n"))
    b17.configure(text=new_months[16], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[16])+"\n-\n"))
    b18.configure(text=new_months[17], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[17])+"\n-\n"))
    b19.configure(text=new_months[18], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[18])+"\n-\n"))
    b20.configure(text=new_months[19], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[19])+"\n-\n"))
    b21.configure(text=new_months[20], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[20])+"\n-\n"))

    b22.configure(text=new_months[21], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[21])+"\n-\n"))
    b23.configure(text=new_months[22], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[22])+"\n-\n"))
    b24.configure(text=new_months[23], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[23])+"\n-\n"))
    b25.configure(text=new_months[24], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[24])+"\n-\n"))
    b26.configure(text=new_months[25], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[25])+"\n-\n"))
    b27.configure(text=new_months[26], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[26])+"\n-\n"))
    b28.configure(text=new_months[27], bg=bg1, fg=fg1, command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, l1["text"]+" "+str(new_months[27])+"\n-\n"))

    b29.configure(text=new_months[28])
    lower_check(b29, new_months[28])
    b30.configure(text=new_months[29])
    lower_check(b30, new_months[29])
    b31.configure(text=new_months[30])
    lower_check(b31, new_months[30])
    b32.configure(text=new_months[31])
    lower_check(b32, new_months[31])
    b33.configure(text=new_months[32])
    lower_check(b33, new_months[32])
    b34.configure(text=new_months[33])
    lower_check(b34, new_months[33])
    b35.configure(text=new_months[34])
    lower_check(b35, new_months[34])

    b36.configure(text=new_months[35])
    lower_check(b36, new_months[35])
    b37.configure(text=new_months[36])
    lower_check(b37, new_months[36])
    b38.configure(text=new_months[37])
    lower_check(b38, new_months[37])
    b39.configure(text=new_months[38])
    lower_check(b39, new_months[38])
    b40.configure(text=new_months[39])
    lower_check(b40, new_months[39])
    b41.configure(text=new_months[40])
    lower_check(b41, new_months[40])
    b42.configure(text=new_months[41])
    lower_check(b42, new_months[41])

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I'm sure our Python contributors will have some great ideas to improve your code.

Comment: No time for a proper review, so... Ever heard of the [calendar module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/calendar.html#calendar.monthcalendar)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

You import `Tkinter` like that.  Instead, use `import Tkinter as tk` and use `tk.` before each `Tkinter` variable.

> ```
> January = [
>     27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 1, 2,
>     ...
> ```

That code is very repetitive.  Probably the easiest way would be to say something like:

```
ranges = {}
ranges['January'] = ((27, 32), (1, 32), (1, 7))
ranges['February'] = ((31, 32), (1, 30), (1, 13))
...
calendars = {}
for month, start_ends in ranges:
    calendars[month] = sum((list(range(*start_end)) for start_end in start_ends), [])
```

Then instead of using `January`, you could use `calendars['January']`.  It also shortens your code by quite a bit.

> ```
> ht = 2
> bg1 = "blue"
> ...
> ```

Those look like they are constants.  From [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants):

> Constants are usually defined on a module level and written in all capital letters with underscores separating words. Examples include MAX_OVERFLOW and TOTAL.

Taking from that, they should be `HT`, `BG1`, `FG1`, and `CURRENT_YEAR`.

> ```
> def replace(month, operation):
> ```

The name `replace` makes it look like it is actually doing some replacing, but the code doesn't look like that.  It looks like you are getting an adjacent month not replacing anything.  I would give it some more appropriate name.  Also, you should use a number for `operation` instead of a string:

```
def adjacent(month, shift=1):
    return months[(months.index(month) + shift) % len(months]
```

That way, you can use `adjacent(month, -1)` to get the previous month, and `adjacent(month)` to get the next month.  You should read more about the [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operator.

> ```
> if l1["text"] == "February": # I corrected your spelling mistake
>     change_month(February)
>     load()
> elif l1["text"] == "March":
>     ...
> ```

If we had left the calendars as separate variables like you originally defined them, my fault would be that you call `load()` once for each `if` and `elif` statement.  Since they are all calling it, you should just put that at the end.  We aren't doing that, though, so you can replace all of those `if` and `elif` statements with this:

```
change_month(months.get(l1["text"], "January")) # I used "January" as the default since you used that month in your else block.
load()
```

That dramatically cuts the number of lines.

`replace_back()`, `replace_back2()`, `replace_forward()`, and `replace_forward2()` all do the exact same thing.  `replace_back()` and `replace_forward()` take the `event` argument, but the actual code part of the functions are all identical.  That means that you can put them all into one.  If you want to be able to take an `event` argument, but you want to be able not to, use `def replace(event=None):`

> ```
> s = open("Months 2016/" + l1["text"] + ".txt", "w")
> ```

I have two problems with that: you should be using a `with` block and you should be using string formatting:

```
with open("Months 2016/{month}.txt".format(month=l1["text"]), "w") as s:
    text = text1.get(1.0, END)
    s.write(text.rstrip() + "\n")
```

You don't need `try` and `finally` when you use a `with` block.

> ```
> Label(frame_days, text="Sunday").pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=X)
> Label(frame_days, text="Monday").pack(...)
> ...
> ```

Look at how repetitive that is!  You should use a loop:

```
for day in ("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", ...):
    tk.Label(frame_days, text=day).pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=1, fill=tk.X)
```

But more repetition is found here:

> ```
> frame_wk1 = Frame(left_frame)
> framw_wk2 = Frame(left_frame)
> ...
> b1 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[0], ...)
> b2 = Button(frame_wk1, text=January[1], ...)
> ...
> b1.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)
> b2.pack(side=LEFT, expand=1, fill=BOTH)
> ...
> ```

You have about 40 lines that are almost identical.  That is a definite sign that you should be using a loop:

```
buttons = []
january = ranges['January']
before_and_after = list(range(*january[0])) + list(range(*january[-1])) # Days that are not actually in this month
calendar = months['January']
for j in range(len(calendar)):
    if not j % 7: # If j % 7 is equal to 0.  That way, we create a new frame for every seven j's.
        frame = tk.Frame(left_frame)
        frame.pack(expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
    keywords = {
        'text': calendar[0]
        'height': ht,
        'width': 5,
    }

    if j in before_and_after:
        keywords.update({
            'state': 'disabled'
        }
    else:
        keywords.update({
            'bg': BG1,
            'fg': FG1,
            'command': lambda k=j: text1.insert(1.0, "{} {}\n-\n".format(l1["text"], calendar[k])),
        }
    button = tk.Button(frame, **keywords)
    button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=1, fill=tk.BOTH)
    buttons.append(button)
```

I haven't actually tested that code, but it should at least give you the idea.

> ```
> b1.configure(text=new_months[0])
> upper_check(b1, new_months[0])
> b2.configure(text=new_months[1])
> upper_check(b2, new_months[1])
> ...
> ```

Yet again we have repetition.  In the code above I created a list called `buttons`, so we can use that here:

```
def change_month(new_months):
    before = list(range(*january[0]))
    after = list(range(*january[-1]))
    for i, (button, month) in enumerate(zip(buttons, new_months)):
        in_before = i in before
        in_after = i in after:
        if in_before or in_after:
            button.configure(text=month)
        if in_before:
            upper_check(button, month)
        elif in_after:
            lower_check(button, month)
        else:
            button.configure(
                text=month, bg=BG1, fg=FG1,
                command=lambda: text1.insert(1.0, "{} {}\n-\n".format(l1["text"], month))
            )
```

The lesson to be learned from this: if it looks repetitive, you can probably solve it with a loop.